# Monitoring Spark Cluster from Terminal (without UI)

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to monitor Spark without any UI directly from terminal ?
I would like to fire commands and get the health status of my cluster (driver & workers) among other things, without having to leave the terminal every time and refresh the UI, let alone when UI access is not an option (corp firewalls or else)

- I know there is a REST interface - that's where the UI sucks up its info - but curling that is rather painstaking.
- Nagios / Ganglia are also UI based if I'm not mistaken
- Lynx is a terminal browser, but this is still a terminal UI.
- SparkListeners can do a fair job, but that is not interactive at runtime

I think it would be a convenient thing to have when doing system/cluster administration tasks.
Any ideas ?